# talend - retry subjob based on REST request results

Tags: rest, talend

I have a RESTful api I am trying to consume using talend
 in order to get data 2 api calls are needed, the first generates an ID for your report, which you then use to make a consecutive api call using that ID to get your data results

the issue is if the requested report in the 2nd api call has not yet completed it will return

```
[{data:{string:"Requested report ### has not finished processing yet, please try again later"}}]
```

so, i put a tJava to  thread(5000) to stagger the 1st api call (tRestClient2) from the 2nd api call (tRestClient1), but I could forsee this being an issue

what i want to do is evaluate the 2nd tRest request result (tFileOutputJSON_3), and if it equals "Requested report...", then requeue the 2nd tRest request until the data is ready

here is a screenshot of my job

[image]

Comment: from your tJavaRow_1 you can start a while loop using tLoop and set a global variable to state whether you should continue the loop or not, first instance you should set it to a condition what while loop continues, then you go to tRestClient_1 and fetch the values and parse tFileoutputJSON_3 and based on response you set this value of this globalvariable to either continue while loop or exit it. you may even want to add a tSleep to add a delay

Comment: I would guess you modified your workflow for the sreenshot but If this is not the case you should read [this good practices guide](https://de.talend.com/blog/2015/12/07/talend-%E2%80%9Cjob-design-patterns%E2%80%9D-and-best-practices) especially **Canvas Workflow & Layout** part.

Comment: @JulienBreuil i did modify but that link is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Like always there is ton of solutions.
But you are not far from what you want. This following design should respect your expectation :

I kept your components as I don't really know what you are doing inside(I retired tLogrow to make things concise). But I reorganized scheduling links.

> tJava
>      |onSubjobOk
>    tRestClient -- >
>   tFileOutputJSON
>      |onSubjobOk
>   tFileInputJSON-- >
>   tExtractJSONFields -- > tJavaRow
>       |onSubjobOk
>   tSetGlobalVar<sup>1</sup>
>       |onSubjobOk
>   tLoop<sup>2</sup> -- iterate (order1)-- > tRestClient -- >
>   tHashOutput<sup>3</sup>
>      |      -- iterate
>   (order2)-- > tHashInput<sup>4</sup> -- > tJavaRow<sup>5</sup>
>      |      -- iterate
>   (order3)-- > tSleep<sup>6</sup>
>      |onSubjobOk
>   tHashInput<sup>7</sup> -- > tFileOutputJSON

<sup>1</sup>:Use a variable to manage the loop.
<sup>2</sup>:Use a While loop. Leave declaration and iteration blank (""), and put your condition using the previously initialized variable.<sup>3</sup>:Do not use Append as you want to fetch new result at each loop.
<sup>4</sup>:Link it to your HashOutput and do not clear cache.
<sup>5</sup>:Do your work here. Do not forget to update the global variable.
<sup>6</sup>:Can be placed before the call if most calls required time before report getting ready.
<sup>7</sup>:Link it to your HashOutput too, you will be able to fetch the data that made a end to the loop.

Comment: Somehow i can't post if I do use breakline. I will try to edit but at the moment I do not understand why the site is blocking my answer when well formated.

Comment: Well, it should be readable now but I still can't move the line ^3 at the bottom of my post.